# Failed building wheel for psycopg2. I put: "pip install psycopg2". I am on windows, with pycharm

Tags: pip, pycharm, psycopg2, python-wheel

```
Collecting psycopg2
Using cached psycopg2-2.9.1.tar.gz (379 kB)
Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Building wheels for collected packages: psycopg2
Building wheel for psycopg2 (setup.py) ... error

ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:

building 'psycopg2._psycopg' extension
error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with 
  "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/

  ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Failed building wheel for psycopg2
Running setup.py clean for psycopg2
Failed to build psycopg2
Installing collected packages: psycopg2
Running setup.py install for psycopg2 ... error
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:

running build_ext
building 'psycopg2._psycopg' extension
error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with 
  "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
  ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\josue\desktop\python\db\01 - introdb\venv\scripts\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpsycopg2%5D+error%3A+Microsoft+Visual+C%2B%2B+14.0+or+greater+is+required

Answer (score 0):

```
https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
```

go to this link and download vs studio

https://i.stack.imgur.com/zz39s.png
install "Data Storage And processing build tools"

than click on modify

After downloading click on launch

than type

```
pip install psycogp2
```

that should solve the problem